# Visual Leak Detector does not print any leak compared to crtdbg

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, visual-leak-detector

i've search a lot for this question, but could find a solution yet for it.

I recently downloaded VLD 2.5 and compiled it from scratch, both for Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. Before I'd use it in my projects I thought i run the tests provided by the package. But all the tests fail.

Same behavior for all the test suites, reported at https://vld.codeplex.com/workitem/10617

The MFC-Test application outputs the following:
[image: Output of vldmfc.exe]

The point here is: CRT detects the leaks, a CString object allocated by the application, VLD don't.

What am I missing ?

Comment: It might be data that is allocated on program initialization and have a life-time of the whole program where it's released after CRTDBG prints its output. I.e. a false positive. VLD might have its hooks later and therefore see the release, or it might know about this special case and not report it?

Comment: No, that "could" be an issue, but it's for sure that the **new** is done after initialization of VLD. The VLD patches all the entry points of the crt, i've debugged it in the morning. But the problem is, that the free block is not counted. It looks like a problem in the VLD, but i dont know where.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  It would help others who might want to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Just use the source code and compile **vldmfc**

Comment: **Add:** The blockmap for the allocations is empty, the application does not collect any heap information.

Comment: HM, it worked out on other computers. I think its related to the global flags. Someone any knowledge on VLD vs. Gflags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for it. Global Flags are set permanently. You need to reset them in case of such an error.

Look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` and reset `GlobalFlag` to 0 (or use gflags.exe).

Cheers,
luis.